# Storing a unique list of ordered Strings as the key in a HashMap

Tags: java

I've run into some problem here. I need to store a list of Strings versus a float value as an entry. I am thinking of using a `HashMap`, but that is creating some problem.

I want to store three String values against a float value in one entry.
Something like this

```
"X","Y","Z" -> 0.5 
"P","Q","R" -> 0.2
"Y","X","Z" -> 0.6
```

The thing is the three key values are unique in their ordering and should not be repeated.
I am trying something like these

```
HashMap<List<String>, Float> q= new HashMap<List<String>, Float>();
```

But I think it does nothing to maintain uniqueness and more so I am not able to insert values into it using

```
q.put(["N","V","D"], 0.5F);
//The above gives error
```

---

### **CONFESSION**

I was suggested this approach, but I cannot understand how to implement the `MyKeyClass`.
If this is a correct way, please help me out with this !!

```
Map<MyKeyClass, Integer> map = new HashMap<MyKeyClass, Integer>();
map.put(new MyKeyClass("A", "B","C"), 1);
map.put(new MyKeyClass("A", "C","B"), 2);
```

Comment: The `List<String>` approach should work fine (though using a class is probably the better approach), and will maintain uniqueness correctly (two `List`s are considered equal if they return the same elements in the same order).  Your syntax for creating a list is incorrect though.  If you get it compiling, it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in your `MyKeyClass` such that order of elements can be differentiated using `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

```
class MyKeyClass extends Object {
   String a;
   String b;
   String c;

   public MyKeyClass(String a, String b, String c) {
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
       this.c = c;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (!(obj instanceof MyKeyClass))
          return false;
       else {
           MyKeyClass mkc = (MyKeyClass) obj;
            return this.a.equals(mkc.a) && this.b.equals(mkc.b)
                  && this.c.equals(mkc.c);

       }
    }
    @Override
    // This needs to be implemented shrewedly.I think my logic is bad.
    public int hashCode(){
       return a.hashCode()-b.hashCode()-c.hashCode();
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since its `HashMap<List<String>, Float>`, you need to provide a `list` as `key`.

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("N");
myList.add("V");
myList.add("D");

q.put(myList, 0.5F);
```

Also, the suggestion given to you was quite good, and you can do something like this for your `MyKey` class.

```
class MyKey{
    String s1;
    String s1;
    String s1;

    public MyKey(){}
    public MyKey(String s1, String s2, String s3){
    this.s1 = s1;
    this.s2 = s2;
    this.s3 = s3;
    }

    // Getter Setter for s1,s2,s3 - Remove them, to make it immutable (as @ Bhesh Gurung suggested)
    // Implement the equals() & hashCode() methods
}
```

Comment: You still have to add `equals` and `hashCode` to `MyKey`. Otherwise you don't get unique keys.

Comment: Provided the update to my answer, just as you'd commented! Thnx for the suggestion anyways!

Comment: Using a `List` as key of a `Map` is a sign of bad design.

Comment: It would also be better to make `MyKey` immutable by not having setters and making the no-arg constructor private.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - Agreed! But that's what the OP had done. I've no rights to change that. Had thought of giving a suggestion, but seems that is the OP's requirement! All upto the person wanting to implement it!

Comment: @BheshGurung - Good suggestion! Thnx:)

Comment: I guess OP's problem started when he/she tried to use `List` as key otherwise the problem would have never came in the context. As part of our mission, we can say users *your current design won't support what you need, instead you can foo the bar with baz*.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - You're always welcome to provide a fruitful edit to my post!

Answer (score 2):

Does the key for the HashMap have to specifically be a list of Strings?  Instead of using a list of Strings as the key to your Hashmap, why not just combine all your strings together into one string, and use that single string as the key?  Perhaps something like this:

```
HashMap<String, Float> q = new HashMap<String, Float>();
q.put("N:V:D", 0.5F);

//add new key-value pair to HashMap
String a = "A";
String b = "B";
String c = "C";
String abc = a + ":" + b + ":" + c;
q.put(abc, 0.7F);

//retrieve value from HashMap
float value = q.get(abc);
```

**EDIT:**

However, as others have pointed out, it is probably better to store the Strings in a class and instead use that as the key.  If you decide to change the number of Strings or use a different data type for the key, it would be much easier to make that change.

Comment: And what happens when you have `N:, V, D` and `N, :V, D` as two different keys?  Embedding multiple values in a single String is not an object-oriented way of solving a problem, and in this case, is fragile.

Comment: I just kind of assumed the key strings would include only letters.  If they can include any and all valid characters for the string, then this solution wouldn't work.

Comment: @MarkPeters Ah, that's a good point about being fragile.  Having the key be a class containing the Strings would be a better solution.